# jquery load runs from dev console and not from js file (enclosed in ready)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

the following code is the relevant part of a js script, mostly it works fine, apart from the load function which refuses to work no matter what i do, yet it works if I copy paste it to the console of chrome
I can't seems to notice the issue

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#addTask').click(function(event){
    var content=$('#currentTask').val();
    $.post('tasks', {param1: content}, function(data) {
        $('#tasksBlock').load(location.href+' #tasksBlock')
    });
})});
```

Comment: have you added this `js` file just after `jquery.min.js`?

Comment: it feels like the string contentation is the culprit. what is the actual url you are referring to?

abc.com/#tasksBlock or abc.com#tasksBlock?

Your code caters to the second case.

Comment: @Curiousdev yes it's the last js ever included, and it contains other jquery in same file

Comment: @Satpal ofcourse, otherwise it wouldn't work in console

Comment: @jonLuci can you clarify your comment further please!

Comment: to debug your problem since you say it runs fine from the console, can you wrap $('#tasksBlock').load(location.href+' #tasksBlock') as setTimeout(function () { $('#tasksBlock').load(location.href+' #tasksBlock') }, 1000); and then see if this issue occurs or not.

Comment: @jonLuci nothing changed

Comment: 1. what is the url from where u want the data to load? abc.com/#tasksBlock or abc.com#tasksBlock, the difference is the / here.
2.  and can u open the link in a new tab and see the output? maybe the url itself is 404.

Comment: found the issue finally, the page for some reason cached the js and didn't refresh it on reloads, sorry to trouble you.

Answer (score 0):

if you face same issue, make sure the js is not being cached by checking the content of the file through the sources tab of the chrome or fire fox developer tools